# Updating a wordpress post from php file

Tags: php, wordpress

With the use of update_post_meta, is it possible that I call a php file to update the post?

**updatePost.php**

```
<?php update_post_meta(7789, 'wpcf-ticket-location', 'Location1'); ?>
```

This doesn't work when the php file is called. I don't really understand how this update_post_meta works after reading wordpress documentations..

Thanks!

Comment: is that the entire script? you'd need to include the wordpress libraries first, before any of that would work.

Comment: Oh is that so! dang I thought it would work anywhere in any php file geez..

Comment: Nope. Just because WP is written in PHP doesn't mean you can simply throw WP function calls into any PHP script. WP isn't a loadable php extension/module. it's just a series of .php scripts.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call wp-config file to call update_post_meta in your php file.

Comment: I tried this:
require_once "/wp-config.php";    update_post_meta(7789, 'wpcf-ticket-location', 'Location1');
Does not work..